# firebase messaging.getToken() return null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following this tutorial [Set Up a JavaScript Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client). When I ran the page for the first time, I clicked on "Block" rather than "Allow" when the page asked me to show notifications.
After removing the site from the Chrome blocked list [Turn notifications on or off](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), `messaging.getToken()` always returns `null`.

I tried `messaging.deleteToken()` but this requires a valid (not null) token anyway.

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you add some code examples, of what you are doing?

Comment: @Jacob

I got from this link [
Set Up a JavaScript Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

This scritp is the core code

<pre> <code>
messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
  console.log('Notification permission granted.');
  // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
  // ...
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});
</code></pre>

Comment: Make sure you have added access in the manifest/token for whatever environment you are in. The example in the Android environment you need to add the access to the manifest for notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You must start a server in the folder of your project

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

and access like this
http://127.0.0.1:8080/

It will NEVER work if you sign in from another folder like this
http://127.0.0.1/miproyecto/
http://localhost/myproject/

remember to create the file firebase-messaging-sw.js in the root
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive?hl=en-419

---

Debes iniciar un servidor en la carpeta de tu proyecto

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

y acceder así
http://127.0.0.1:8080/

NUNCA funcionara si accedes desde otra carpeta así
http://127.0.0.1/miproyecto/
http://localhost/miproyecto/

recuerda crear el archivo firebase-messaging-sw.js en la raiz
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

1. Click "View site information" icon
2. Set Notification to "Allow"
   [Allow Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkpoR.png)
3. Click on Cookies
4. Select the host name (localhost in my case)
   [remove cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n27LH.png)
5. Click on Remove
6. Click on Done

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to make a **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file in your *root repo* **or** *public folder inside root repo*. And then, open that file via your localhost server. Ex : *localhost:5000/firebase-messaging-sw.js*.

If you still get an error page, you need to create **manifest.json** file. In this file, put your *gcm_sender_id* or *messagingSenderID*.

```
{
     "gcm_sender_id" : "587997283287" 
}
```

In my case, I can resolve this problem.